# Can't scroll up list on web iPhone

Tags: css, reactjs, iphone, mobile

I'm building a reactjs widget which has scrollable lists (vertically) inside it, which takes the entire viewport on mobile (I prevent the default for "touchmove" on the window so as not to scroll the background).

But when I open the widget on iPhone (tested on both Safari and Chrome), I can scroll down the list, but can't scroll back up! if I want to scroll back up, I need to scroll a bit down before I scroll up (one action, without lifting the finger).
I also have reversed lists (same design, only with flex-direction: column-reverse), and I have the exact same behavior regardless of the flex direction.

I also noticed that the "touchmove" event on the list is not firing when I can scroll, but it is firing when I can't.

It works great on desktop, tablets (iPad as well) and android devices - just not on iPhone.

I need the scroll to work both ways on iPhone as well

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake - it was a combination of using body-scroll-lock and preventDefault of "touchmove" on the body.

All fixed now